# Javascript play Audio after other without audio-collapse

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to play one audio after another using Javascript. I get  the audio file name from a vector (int) and from some strings I have created.
This is my code but I can't make it works.

```
var audio = new Audio();
function playAll(){
    var folder_name = "synthex/";
    var file_name = ".sentence"; 
    var audio_file = ".wav";

    for(i=0;i<18;++i)
    {   
    var dir_file = folder_name + voicesClicks[i];
    dir_file = dir_file + file_name;

    if(voicesClicks[i] == null){
        continue;
    }
    //var value = voicesClicks[i];

    dir_file = dir_file + i;
    dir_file = dir_file + audio_file;

    console.log(dir_file);

    audio.src = dir_file;
    audio.play();

    }
}
```

Comment: What are your console errors - if any?

Comment: Show more code, there are several places where this function can raise an error (audio and voicesClick variables are not clear, for instance)

Comment: Hi guys, I have no errors, the only thing that happens is nothing.

Comment: read the mozilla documentation on [HTML5 Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video). none of the code you've posted seems to have any HTML.

Comment: I am working with this part of Javascript code, the only HTML code that I want to link with is this one:
      <input type="button" value="Reproduce" id="btnSubmit" onClick="playAll()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem that I find with your code is, `audio`'s src keep changing in each iteration, so even if the `audio.src` value is a vaild wav file, you code would end up playing the last one...

I had a similar requirement, I did...

```js
function playAll() {
  // CHANGE this list to as per your requirement.
  var urls = ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Beatles_eleanor_rigby.ogg',
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg'
  ];
  var idx = 0;
  var aud = new Audio();
  aud.src = urls[idx];
  aud.addEventListener('ended', function() { // for automatically starting the next.
    idx++;
    if (idx === urls.length) idx = 0;
    aud.src = urls[idx];
    aud.play();
  });
  aud.play();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", playAll); // you can change this to button.onclick handler.
```

Edit: you can change the `urls` to ...

```
var urls = [];
for(i=0;i<18;++i){
    if(!voicesClicks[i]){
        continue;
    }
    urls.push(folder_name + voicesClicks[i] + file_name + i + audio_file);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(urls));  // for debug
```